# IBM Worklight - Push notification error when trying to build and deploy the app

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

We are getting the below error while running the sample code for push notification in iOS:

> [2013-08-16 15:02:50] FWLST1044W: An APNS certificate exists, but the
>   push sender element was not found in the application descriptor. Push
>   notifications will not be enabled

Our APNS certificate name used: apns-certificate-sandbox.p12
Our application-descriptor.xml - iPhone element:

```
<iphone bundleId="com.companyname.abc.cde" version="1.0">
       <worklightSettings include="true"/>
       <pushSender password="***@push"/>
       <security>
           <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
           <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
       </security>
</iphone>
```

Answer (score 1):

edit application-descriptor.xml of you application and make sure that  or  environments has a  element. See slide 47 of http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf

Comment: Hi Anton we have already added this in our app from day 1, please suggest if any changes needed for this to work.

Comment: It throws this error during build despite having placed the certificate in the application root folder and using the correct password? Please verify.

Comment: @djrecker, any news here? can you try with a new app? Just add an iPhone environment, place the certificate, add the pushSender element and and password, and build.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you have iPhone and iPad environment you need to put the certificate.p12 on environment folder. It's worked for me.

[image: iPhone environment]